# Background events in progressive web apps? (building an alarm clock app)

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am playing around with progressive web apps, and one scenario I wanted to try building was an alarm clock app.

I figure to make this app work properly, it will have to run in the background and become active once the internal conditions (current time === alarm time) have been met.

Is this possible? Or do progressive web apps not yet have the freedom to operate in the background/access phone features through API's.

Thanks!

Comment: To everyone who wants this functionality, please star and comment on the Google issue requesting it to motivate them to act: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=889077

Answer (score 7):

Setting background timers isn't yet possible. The [ScheduledTask API](https://www.w3.org/TR/task-scheduler/) is probably do what you want, but it's still being discussed, implemented and so on.

Comment: Thanks! That does look like it would work for what I had in mind, but I can't find much information about it online. Is there a timeline on when it could become a feature, or is there any way to enable it as an experimental feature on a personal device?

Comment: @JoshuaLonganecker Not that I know of, no…

Comment: Is there any news about when this is going to be available?