# Is it possible to set the alarm by PWA? (building a timer/alarm clock app)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, progressive-web-apps

I am building a PWA application that works like a pomodoro clock. So it counts down 25 minutes and informs the user when the time is up.

I was thinking of several solutions.
- When the PWA application starts it sets the alarm built into the phone
- The PWA app runs in the background all the time, and it triggers its own alarm.

My application keeps data in a realtime database in firebase about when the timer will end. So I was thinking about using the firebase function that checks how much time is left, but it's probably not possible because the functions are quickly lost.

I am also thinking about a separate back end that would check if the time has already elapsed and send a push notification to the phone but I do not know how to go about it and whether it will be a good solution.

I would like the application PWA to inform the user when the time runs out. Especially when it is turned off. For example, by notification or alarm. What tool can I use to make it possible (getting notifications / beep sound when the time is up)?

Comment: FYI, this is a too broad question. Reread [ask] and [help/on-topic] how and what is not.

Comment: To everyone who wants this functionality, please star and comment on the Google issue requesting it to motivate them to act: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=889077

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Background events in progressive web apps? (building an alarm clock app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944167/background-events-in-progressive-web-apps-building-an-alarm-clock-app)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

'Setting background timers isn't yet possible. The ScheduledTask API is probably do what you want, but it's still being discussed, implemented and so on.'

Refer [Background events in progressive web apps? (building an alarm clock app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944167/background-events-in-progressive-web-apps-building-an-alarm-clock-app).

Comment: Set timeout works well if the PWA keeps open in the foreground. Making use of fact that AMOLED screen turned off when showing black color, we can just show a blank black screen and keep the screen awake using WakeLock API. I've tried it by using 20m using setTimeout, it works. Doesn't drain much energy too.