# Can a PWA schedule notifications when closed?

Tags: progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I'm developing a TODO-list PWA which should display the tasks of the day every day at 8:00am, even when the app is closed (similar to an alarm clock).

Is there a way to achieve this with PWAs? (Mainly targeting Chrome/Android)

So far, in my service worker I have (simplified)

```js
self.addEventListener("message", (event) => {
    // Workflow: The app sends a message that the timer should be set.
    const prom = new Promise((resolveIt) =>
      self.setTimeout(() => showAlarmAndResolve(resolveIt, event.data), '<timeout_in_ms>')
    );
    // tell the service worker to remain alive until promise is resolved
    event.waitUntil(prom); 
  }
});

async function showAlarmAndResolve(resolveIt, text) {
  const options = {
    body: text,
    tag: "todo-alert",
  };
  await self.registration.showNotification(
    "Your tasks for today",
    options
  );
  resolveIt();   // allow the service worker to terminate
}
```

Without the `event.waitUntil`, the notification is not displayed when I close the app on my phone (or close the browser tab), with it, it is displayed.
However, keeping the service worker alive for half a day somehow seems like a really bad idea - and furthermore, I read (here: [Best practice for keeping timer running in PWA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58244539/best-practice-for-keeping-timer-running-in-pwa)) that on Android the service worker might terminate anyway after ~20 minutes.

How can I implement such an alarm clock like functionality?

Some (older) questions do not really give that much help / hope...
[Background events in progressive web apps? (building an alarm clock app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36944167/background-events-in-progressive-web-apps-building-an-alarm-clock-app)
[Is it possible to set the alarm by PWA? (building a timer/alarm clock app)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58240785/is-it-possible-to-set-the-alarm-by-pwa-building-a-timer-alarm-clock-app)

Comment: To everyone who wants this functionality, please star and comment on the Google issue requesting it to motivate them to act: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=889077

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Chrome experimented with this functionality via [Notification Triggers](https://web.dev/notification-triggers/), and after running an [origin trial](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/origin-trials/), the team decided not to move ahead. If anything changes, there will be updates in the [Chromium issue tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=889077).

You can achieve similar once-a-day functionality, without any guarantees about *when* during the day the event will fire, by using the [Periodic Background Sync API](https://web.dev/periodic-background-sync/). If your users needed exact control over when the notification is shown, this wouldn't help. Additionally, it's only supported if a user has gone through the installation flow for your PWA.

Comment: Ok, this answers the question, so despite saying "no, that's not possible", thank you for that explanation! 
Meanwhile, I started to use push notifications with a cron job for that purpose ... not really happy about this, but it'll do the job for my use case.